# Plotly - I want to color the Y axis tick text based on value

Tags: graph, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash, plotly-python

My questions is similar to one that's been asked but in a different language. I'm using plotly in python, to build dash web app dashboards and I have graphs with a y-axis range from negative values to positive values. I would like to leave the positive values black, but I would like to change the negative values to be red (preferably with parentheses around them as well, but the red color is the more important item).

From my research, it seems that there is no native way to do this. I'm up for a complicated solution if that's what it takes. When I inspect the element in the web interface, I can see the html code that shows the RGB values for the text of each tick, but I cannot seem to figure out where I can modify the colors independently of the other tick texts. I've started looking for the source file that is used to format these things so that I can potentially add the logic to it.

The similar question is here and it was asked for JavaScript: [Plotly - I want to color each X Axis value in different color based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884619/plotly-i-want-to-color-each-x-axis-value-in-different-color-based-on-condition)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to color ticktext in plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58183962/how-to-color-ticktext-in-plotly)